# How to get Firefox to stop opening searches in another tab?

Tags: firefox, search, browser-tabs

This may seem like a dumb question but how do I stop Firefox from opening up a Google search in a new tab?

I usually open a new tab first before searching and if I don't then I don't want it open in a new tab.

Comment: What OS and which version of Firefox?

Comment: ...and what plugins do you have installed?

Comment: are you in China? I noticed that in China, all search engines have the irritating behaviour of opening websites in a new tab...

Comment: I choose not to answer that question in order to maintain my anonymity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a configuration setting you can change to keep Firefox from opening in a new tab:

1. Open a new tab and type `about:config` in the address bar
2. Find the key `browser.search.openintab`
3. Double click the setting to toggle the value to `false`

Comment: ya know, i might have done this then forgot... *smacks forehead* Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not get this behavior in my Firefox.

I have [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122) extension installed which seems to have a checkbox to force search results to a new tab (it is unchecked).

Do you have this installed and,

- Tab Mix Plus Options

  - Events

    - Tab Opening

      - Open tabs from: Search bar -- checked?

Answer (score 1):

Set `browser.newtab.url` to blank in **about:config**

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the Google Search bar.

[image]

Comment: Nope just regular search box.